# how to Injection a FacesConverter or managed bean from a lib/jar file?

Tags: jsf, ejb, war, cdi

I try to build a JSF 2.0 Web application which is using libraries including EJBs and FacesConverters/ManagedBeans.

My war file looks like this:

```
-WEB-INF/
 |-beans.xml
 |-lib/
 |  |-myejb.jar
 |  |-myconverter.jar
```

both jar files contain also a beans.xml file placed into the META-INF folder.
The strange thing is, that the EJBs are working well.
But my converter included in the myconverter.jar file is not seen form my web application. I got the following message:

javax.faces.FacesException: Ausdrucksfehler: Benanntes Objekt org.imixs.VectorConverter nicht gefunden.

When I put the converter class directly into the classes from my web module it works.

The converter class looks like this:

```
...
@FacesConverter(value="org.imixs.VectorConverter")
public class VectorConverter implements Converter {
```

I am using no faces-config.xml

the converter is added in my xhmtl file like this:

```
<h:inputTextarea required="false"
    value="#{teamController.members}">
    <f:converter converterId="org.imixs.VectorConverter" />
 </h:inputTextarea>
```

So my question is: why is the converter not seen when it is placed into a jar module?

I am running the app on GlassFish 3.1.1

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `myconverter.jar` also contain a `/META-INF/faces-config.xml`? I think this is required so the your  container also scans for JSF annotations in the JAR file. An empty `faces-config.xml` like this should to the job:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.0">

</faces-config>
```